# Which Mysql database Wordpress using in case of deploy using Docker?

Tags: docker

i'm learning about Docker and have some question i want you guys to help me with.
 I followed this tutorial to deploy wordpress site on to my host on Amazon EC2.
https://github.com/eugeneware/docker-wordpress-nginx
The point is i don't know which Database that my WP using. Can some one help me clarify about this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to run everything in a single container, I'd recommend using the official WordPress and MySQL images.

The WordPress image on Docker Hub also has an example docker-compose file that allows you to start both containers in a single command; https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Comment: When I tested Wordpress installation with Kontena I chose MariaDB for database because the image size and memory consumption was smaller than with MySQL image. https://github.com/kontena/examples/tree/master/wordpress